# Trying to group by but only specific rows based on their value

Tags: pandas

I am finding this issue quite complex:

I have the following df:

```
values_1    values_2    values_3    id    name
 0.1          0.2          0.3       1   AAAA_living_thing
 0.1          0.2          0.3       1   AAA_mammals
 0.1          0.2          0.3       1   AA_dog
 0.2          0.4          0.6       2   AAAA_living_thing
 0.2          0.4          0.6       2   AAA_something
 0.2          0.4          0.6       2   AA_dog
```

The ouput should be:

```
values_1    values_2    values_3    id    name
 0.3          0.6          0.9       3   AAAA_living_thing
 0.1          0.2          0.3       1   AAA_mammals
 0.1          0.2          0.3       1   AA_dog
 0.2          0.4          0.6       2   AAA_something
 0.2          0.4          0.6       2   AA_dog
```

It would be like a `group_by().sum()` but only the `AAAA_living_thing` as the rows below are childs of `AAAA_living_thing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seperate the dataframe first by using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and getting the rows only with `AAAA_living_thing` and without. Then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and finally [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them back together:

```
temp = df.query('name.str.startswith("AAAA")').groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
temp2 = df.query('~name.str.startswith("AAAA")')
final = pd.concat([temp, temp2])
```

**Output**

```
   id               name  values_1  values_2  values_3
0   3  AAAA_living_thing       0.3       0.6       0.9
1   1        AAA_mammals       0.1       0.2       0.3
2   1             AA_dog       0.1       0.2       0.3
4   2      AAA_something       0.2       0.4       0.6
5   2             AA_dog       0.2       0.4       0.6
```

---

Another way would be to make a unique identifier for rows which are *not* `AAAA_living_thing` with `np.where` and then `groupby` on `name + unique identifier`:

```
s = np.where(df['name'].str.startswith('AAAA'), 0, df.index)
final = df.groupby(['name', s], as_index=False).sum()
```

**Output**

```
                name  values_1  values_2  values_3  id
0  AAAA_living_thing       0.3       0.6       0.9   3
1        AAA_mammals       0.1       0.2       0.3   1
2      AAA_something       0.2       0.4       0.6   2
3             AA_dog       0.1       0.2       0.3   1
4             AA_dog       0.2       0.4       0.6   2
```

Comment: Hi @Erfan, what if I only knew that the str begun with AAAA_ instead of the complete name?

Comment: `np.where(df['name'].str.startswith('AAAA'), 0, df.index)` may be @ge00rge

Comment: We have switch to `str.startswith` instead of `.eq`, see edit @ge00rge